# Clipping a rhizome

Tags: hops, rhizome

I have a hop few plants that will be a year old next month. How can I tell if it's ok to clip a rhizome to give to my buddy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never done this yet myself.  I have a book called "The Homebrewer's Garden", it says to root prune or divide every three years, my oldest plants are starting their third year.  It says to divide before any growth shows and to cut the rhizome into several pieces, making sure each piece has both roots and shoots.